# My layout file is not showing in setContent(R.layout.xml file)..?

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin

I have written my code but in the code when I use `view = ..(R.layout.my_message)` it shows error as such file does not exist while it is already created. While rewriting name again I got option of `activity_list_item` which is not exist in my code. What I do to get my layout xml file?

**Project Structure**
[image: Project Structure]

I have tried alot and search too but found nothing.

```
    class MessageAdapter(val context: Context) : RecyclerView.Adapter<MessageAdapter.MessageViewHolder>(){

        companion object {
            const val VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_SENT = 1
           const val VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_RECEIVED = 2
        }

        private val messages: ArrayList<Message> = ArrayList()

        fun addMessage(message: Message){
            messages.add(message)
            notifyDataSetChanged()
        }

        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MessageViewHolder {
            val view: View

            if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_SENT) {
              view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.my_message, parent, false)
                return MessageViewHolder(view)
            } else  {
                view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.other_message, parent, false)
                return OtherMessageViewHolder(view)
            }

        }

        override fun getItemCount(): Int {
            return messages.size
        }

        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MessageViewHolder, position: Int) {
            val message = messages.get(position)

            holder.bind(message)
        }

        open inner class MessageViewHolder(view : View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view){
                private var messageText = view.txtMyMessage
                private var timeText = view.txtMyMessageTime
           open fun bind(message: Message){
             messageText.text = message.message
                timeText.text = fromMillisToTimeString(millis = message.time)
            }
        }

        inner class OtherMessageViewHolder (view: View) : MessageViewHolder(view) {

            internal var messageText: TextView
            internal var timeText: TextView
            internal var nameText: TextView
            internal var profileImage: ImageView

            init {

                messageText = itemView.text_message_body as TextView
                timeText = itemView.text_message_time as TextView
                nameText = itemView.text_message_name as TextView
                profileImage = itemView.image_message_profile as ImageView
            }


            fun bind(message: Message) {
                messageText.text = message.message
                timeText.text = fromMillisToTimeString(message.time)
                Utils.displayRoundImageFromUrl(context, message.getSender().getProfileUrl(), profileImage);
            }
        }
        object DateUtils {
            fun fromMillisToTimeString(millis: Long) : String {
                val format = SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a", Locale.getDefault())
                return format.format(millis)
            }
        }
        override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
            val message = messages.get(position)

            return if(message.isSending){
                VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_SENT
            } else {
                VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_RECEIVED
            }
        }

    }
```

**Expected:**
`(R.layout.my_message, parent, false)
(R.layout.other_message, parent, false)`

**Actual:**

`other_message` and `my_message` are unresolved reference.

Comment: It would be better to understand your question if you include whole adapter class.

Comment: @SagarChapagain ok I will do it now

Comment: @SagarChapagain now you can find error

Comment: I think you are trying to use the recyclerview with two layouts depending upon the message type. But you might not have created layouts `my_message` and `other_message` in layouts folder.

Comment: Totally agreed with @SagarChapagain, we can’t provide solutions without seening the whole classes or code snippet. Please share project structure.

Comment: But I have created these layout classes.I have faced the same issue with another project where as I added the code further (R.layout.activity_main) even become disabled

Comment: Perhaps you have a syntax error inside one of your xml files (these layouts or any other resource) that's preventing R.java from being generated correctly.

Comment: I have pasted my project structure image.You can see this too

Comment: @BenP. Please see my code I have pasted the whole adapter code now

Comment: Please tell me where I did wrong in my code so I can fix my code

Comment: @MuneebA. Have you found any error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if you'r sure, that the layouts you mentioned are in the **res/layout** folder, then maybe they just aren't recognized by the AndroidStudio.

so first try to clean / Rebuild you Project:
in AndroidStudio (Mac) click on:

> Build -> Clean Project

then

> Build -> Rebuilt Project

if this doesn't help, then you have to clear the Cache and restart the Android Studio (Mac) :

> File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart...

Comment: I am using Linux ubuntu

Comment: it's the same, you just have to go to the menu and click on "File" then "Invalidate Caches /Restat.."

Comment: what I do now..?

Comment: In android studio you mean?

Comment: just go to Android Studio an in the menu click on "File" then "Invalidate Caches /Restat.."
after Android studio is restarted, the layouts should be now recognized. if not, it means that you maybe have a typo in the name of the layouts, check that as well.

Comment: I have check the names too and applied the cache method too but nothing happens

Comment: If there is a typo error in layout names.then why it is also not showing `activity_main` in the suggestion list too?

Comment: hmm... are you sure that the class R is also imported ?
 ìmport YourPackageName.R;

Comment: Thank you so much for your great help..my problem is sort out now

Comment: happy to help. have fun coding :)

Comment: I have 2 more questions.Can you check them too..?

Comment: I got the same problem and the `File / Invalidate Caches...` solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

Invalidate and restart cache worked for me

Comment: Please consider posting this as a comment instead of an answer.